# Enhanced for loop with std::move_iterator

Tags: c++

How does one iterate with the enhanced for loop using `std::move_iterator`?

Would the following be sufficient?

```c
for ( auto && element : collection )
    // std::move( element );
```

Answer (score 0):

The example you provided is not sufficient, because
`auto&& element` is not of the type as `std::move_iterator`.
With `auto&& element` you will not be able not access the member functions of `std::move_iterator`.

In order to use an enhanced for loop in combination with `std::move_iterator` one needs to generate a vector of `std::move_iterator`s. Just like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {

    std::vector<double> Vec = {1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5};

    typedef std::vector<double>::iterator iter_t;
    std::vector<std::move_iterator<iter_t>> MoItVec(Vec.size());

    std::generate(MoItVec.begin(), MoItVec.end(), 
        [&Vec,n = 0]() mutable
        { 
            auto It = Vec.begin() + n++;
            return  std::move_iterator<iter_t>(It);
        }
    );

    for(auto MoIt : MoItVec)
    {
        std::cout << *MoIt << std::endl;
        //do cool stuff with MoIt
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[You can run the above code online](https://godbolt.org/z/DWVqCN).

IMHO the approach described above is more complicated then just using a standard for loop:

```
for(auto It = Vec.begin(); It != Vec.end(); ++It)
{
    auto MoIt = std::move_iterator<iter_t>(It);
    //do cool stuff with MoIt
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A note on auto&&: This doesn't always declare an rvalue reference, although it looks like it. auto&& is actually a *universal reference* (or *forwarding reference*), meaning the type of "auto &&" deduced will be lvalue reference or rvalue reference, depending on whether we try to deduce the type of an lvalue or an rvalue.

It seems that you just want to move from the elements in your container. In this case, you can also just use normal references and then move from them:

```
void function(X&&);

for (auto& x: vector_of_x) {
    function(std::move(x));
}
```

Additional note: even if you assign the type rvalue reference in your for-loop and then call a function with it, like so:

```
for (X&& x: vector_of_x) {
    function(x);
}
```

this will not work if "function" is declared as above (accepting only rvalue references). This is because you actually pass in an lvalue (x), that just has type rvalue reference (X&&).

Answer (score 0):

You can ***move from*** a variable in a ***range-based-for***.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v1;
v1.push_back(std::make_unique<int>(7));
v1.push_back(std::make_unique<int>(3));
```

moving items from the `vector` ***v1*** to a new `vector` ***v2***:

```
// option 1
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v2;
for(auto& ptr : v1) {
    v2.push_back(std::move(ptr));
}
```

Note that we use `auto&` in the loop above and not `auto&&`, as the deduced type would anyhow be **lvalue reference** to `unique_ptr` (even if using *forwarding reference*: auto&&) - based on the return value of `operator*` on `vector::iterator` which is lvalue in our case<sup>1</sup>.

Another way to move items from `vector` ***v1*** to a new `vector` ***v2*** is:

```
// option 2
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v2 {
    std::make_move_iterator(v1.begin()),
    std::make_move_iterator(v1.end())
};
```

[Both options are fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3eb979116ee6e2eb) and result with the same outcome:

- ***v1*** holds two ***invalidated*** unique_ptrs
- ***v2*** holds two unique_ptrs, holding ***7*** and ***3***

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> The only case where looping over `std::vector` returns **rvalue reference** is with vector of `bool`.</sub>